# firebase database rule allow read/write to specific users with specific info

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase database rule is like the following:

```
    {
      "rules": {
        "users": {
          "$uid": {

            ".read": "auth != null || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'teacher'",
            ".write": "auth != null || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'teacher'"

          }
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is the following:

- Every user can read/write their OWN data only.
- Only users with the value 'teacher' defined in their corresponding child named 'role' can read/write EVERY other users' data.

  How can I achieve this rule setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be what you're looking for:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'teacher'",
      ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'teacher'",
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this:

- teachers have read and write permission to the entire `users` node
- other users have read and write permission to their own node only

Comment: @AHC: I rolled back your edit. The `$uid` node is intentionally nested, that was not a typo.

Answer (score 0):

how abou this one by removing the `$uid`:

```
  {
      "rules": {
        "users": {

            ".read": "auth != null || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'teacher'",
            ".write": "auth != null || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'teacher'"

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing the uid rule does not satisfy the OP's first requirement: "Every user can read/write their OWN data only."